# Convert SVG SMIL animation to CSS animation

Tags: css, animation, svg, css-animations

My current SVG is animated using SVG SMIL animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg height="512px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="512px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g transform="scale(0.8) translate(-0.6, -0.6)">
        <g id="spinner">
            <path d="M50 15A35 35 0 1 0 74.787 25.213" fill="none" stroke="#19a29c" stroke-width="8px"/>
            <path d="M50 0L50 30L66 15L50 0" fill="#19a29c"/>
            <animateTransform attributeName="transform" dur="1.5s" from="0 50 50" repeatCount="indefinite" to="360 50 50" type="rotate"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

SVG SMIL animation is not supported in IE, and is deprecated in Chrome:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-smil

I would like to replace the animation part by CSS animation, making the animation more widely supported and futureproof: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

How can I replace the following SVG SMIL animation by a CSS animation?

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" dur="1.5s" from="0 50 50" repeatCount="indefinite" to="360 50 50" type="rotate"/>
```

Comment: Surely it would be easier just to use a shim which would be a one line change rather than rewrite all your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The animation that is being done using SMIL is a rotate animation where the `#spinner` element gets rotated by 360 degrees every 1.5s and has an infinite loop. The last two parameters of the transform attribute are the `transform-origin` and so to create a CSS equivalent the following must be done:

- Create the animation `@keyframe` rule which does `transform: rotate()` from 0 deg to 360 deg.
- Apply the animation to the `#spinner` element using the `animation` property. Set its duration as 1.5s, iteration count as infinite and timing function as linear. These can either be done using the `animation` shorthand property (or) using the individual `animation-name`, `animation-duration`, `animation-iteration-count` and `animation-timing-function` properties.
- Set the `transform-origin` as 50px 50px for the `#spinner` element.

```css
#spinner {
  animation: rotate 1.5s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: 50px 50px;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<svg height="512px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="512px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="scale(0.8) translate(-0.6, -0.6)">
    <g id="spinner">
      <path d="M50 15A35 35 0 1 0 74.787 25.213" fill="none" stroke="#19a29c" stroke-width="8px" />
      <path d="M50 0L50 30L66 15L50 0" fill="#19a29c" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

---

If you want to save the SVG as a separate file and use it (say with `background-image` etc) then you can add the CSS animation code within the `<style>` tag and place it inside the `<svg>` tag. [Here is a Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/wqurjF3mCaVeiuYeVFsn?p=preview). (**Note:** As Kaiido mentions in comment, this seems to work only in Chrome, Opera.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Kaiido. Let me check that. It works fine in Chrome.

Comment: Yes, seems like there is no workaround for this @Kaiido. Thanks again for pointing it out though. I will add a note into the answer.